# `<router-view />` not working when trying to upgrade to vue 3 from vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

These are my setup files

Router.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router';

import MyComponent from './component/MyComponent.vue';

const routes = [{
  path: 'main/publish/tasks',
  component: MyComponent
}]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

index.js

```
import { createApp, configureCompat } from 'vue';
import router from './Router';
import MainApp from './MainApp.vue';

const app = createApp(MainApp);
app.use(router);

configureCompat({
  // default everything to Vue 2 behavior
  MODE: 2,
});
app.mount('.vue-app');
```

MainApp.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    name: 'MainApp'
  }
</script>
```

Edit:

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
 <div> Hello world </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'MyComponent' 
}
</script>
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "Demo Project",
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "@vue/compat": "^3.2.39",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.39",
        "core-js": "3.1.2",
        "mitt": "^3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "vue": "^3.2.41",
        "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
        "vue-click-outside": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-color": "^2.8.1",
        "vue-custom-element": "^3.3.0",
        "vue-debounce": "^2.6.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
        "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.45",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.31.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.31.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^28.1.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "license-checker": "^25.0.1",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.12.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
        "ts-loader": "^8.0.18",
        "typescript": "^4.0.8",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.46.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.21"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
        "watch": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js --watch",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
        "test": "jest src"
    }
}
```

This code setup leads me to this error

[image]

Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong? Everything works when I remove `<router-view/>`. I can render component fine by importing and adding it to MainApp.vue. But cannot get it rendered through `<router-view/>`.

Comment: Does this error only occur when bundled? i.e. assuming you're using `vite` - does your page work when served using `vite`

Comment: No, I'm using webpack and error occured when served with webpack dev server

Comment: OK - guess the only thing you haven't shown is `./component/MyComponent.vue`

Comment: My bad. It is blank component with only `hello world` inside

Comment: so ... it has no `<script>` and no `<template>`? then it's not a `.vue` file

Comment: It has. I will edit the post with MyComponent file

Comment: well, that's not what you actually said :p - can you also add your `package.json` file

Comment: I have added a package.json file too. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `const routes:[path:'',component:'']`, is this a typo when you copy the code? because this is incorrect syntax it should be `const routes = [{path: 'main/publish/tasks',  component: MyComponent}]`

Comment: yes it is a typo when I copied the code. I will edit the question

Comment: The router starts with `/` - and you have not configured such route path.